# GWT ScrollPanel with Horizontal SimplePanel

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to implement a scrollPanel within a Horizontal Panel.
I read this post 
[GWT Horizontal panel with horizontal scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537722/gwt-horizontal-panel-with-horizontal-scrolling)

The answer seems great, however I'm wondering if ravi wrapped his simple panel with a scroll Panel or vice versa.

Basically I wanted to know how the panels were nested within each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scroll panel is nothing special - it's just a DIV element with some CSS set on it. That's what the answer to the other question means, as a `SimplePanel` is simply a Widget that appears as a DIV.

So what the other answer did was create a scrolling widget by:

- Creating a `SimplePanel` as the content container
- Set some CSS with the  `overflow-x` attribute to the `SimplePanel`
- Setting the content will now have a horizontal scroll bar (due to the CSS attribute).

If you prefer a more direct way of doing this check out [UiBinder](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder). Using it you can combine widgets/CSS/HTML elements in a form closer to how the browser renders your UI. So for example you can create a DIV with the required CSS to achive a scrolling container.

Comment: dispite it has that horizontal scroll bar SimplePanel can contain only one widget . The error said me that. If I add RootPanels as a single 'child', e.g. AbsoluyePanel, it arranges widgets vertically and ignore your css directive :/